# Redux Как сделать меньше когда

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Как не писать в каждом компоненте  mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, connect, а архитектурно(лаконично) все это уменьшить?

```
const mapStateToProps = store => {
    return {
        store...
      }
  }

  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      dispatch...
    }
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант если компонент функциональный можно использовать `react-redux` хуки.

И `connect` не требуется.

Вместо `mapStateToProps`  можно использовать `useSelector`.

А вместо `mapDispatchToProps` использовать  `useDispatch`.

[**Доки**](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks)

Пример cтандартный:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addCount } from "./store/counter/actions";

export const Count = ({ count, addCount }) => {
  return (
    <main>
      <div>Count: {count}</div>
      <button onClick={addCount}>Add to count</button>
    </main>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  count: state.counter.count
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { addCount };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Count);
```

Пример хуками:

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { addCount } from "./store/counter/actions";

export const Count = () => {
  const count = useSelector(state => state.counter.count);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <main>
      <div>Count: {count}</div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(addCount())}>Add to count</button>
    </main>
  );
};
```